# How to add new MIB text file in pysnmp?

Tags: python, pysnmp

Unable to MIB of external device.

I have a IP power bar which can be controlled using SNMP. I am trying to switch off and on outlets using Python script. I have saved new mib at d:\mib
I am trying to set on of the OID to 0. I am calling setCmd function as below

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(setCmd(SnmpEngine(),CommunityData('write_public'),UdpTransportTarget(('xx.xx.xx.xx', 161)),ContextData(),ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.6.4.1.2.1.2.1.3',0).addAsn1MibSource('d:/mib'))))
```

I am getting errors 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(setCmd(SnmpEngine(),CommunityData('write_public'),UdpTransportTarget(('xx.xxx.xx.x', 161)),ContextData(),ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB','1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.6.4.1.2.1.2.1.3',0).addAsn1MibSource('d:/mib'))))
  File "C:\Users\mahemad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\hlapi\asyncore\sync\cmdgen.py", line 217, in setCmd
    lookupMib=options.get('lookupMib', True)))
  File "C:\Users\mahemad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\hlapi\asyncore\cmdgen.py", line 241, in setCmd
    contextData.contextName, vbProcessor.makeVarBinds(snmpEngine, varBinds),
  File "C:\Users\mahemad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\hlapi\varbinds.py", line 39, in makeVarBinds
    __varBinds.append(varBind.resolveWithMib(mibViewController))
  File "C:\Users\mahemad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\smi\rfc1902.py", line 847, in resolveWithMib
    self.__args[0].resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
  File "C:\Users\mahemad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\smi\rfc1902.py", line 368, in resolveWithMib
    ifNotAdded=self.__asn1SourcesOptions.get('ifNotAdded')
  File "C:\Users\mahemad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\smi\compiler.py", line 55, in addMibCompiler
    compiler.addSources(*getReadersFromUrls(*kwargs.get('sources') or defaultSources))
  File "C:\Users\mahemad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysmi\reader\url.py", line 68, in getReadersFromUrls
    raise error.PySmiError('Unsupported URL scheme %s' % sourceUrl)
pysmi.error.PySmiError: Unsupported URL scheme d:/mib
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, MIBs are not *required* with SNMP for as long as you use bare OIDs and values (this is what you seem to do).

If you want to set that OID to value *0* the following managed object specification  should produce SNMP SET PDU you might need:

```
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.6.4.1.2.1.2.1.3'), 0)
```

If you want to use MIBs you should [addAsn1MibSource](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.addAsn1MibSource) method, but pass it a [valid URL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/).

Comment: I modified based on your recommendation to
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(setCmd(SnmpEngine(),CommunityData('write_public'),UdpTransportTarget(('xx.xx.xx.xx', 161)),ContextData(),ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.6.4.1.2.1.2.1.3'),0)))
Still getting Error

Comment: File "C:\Users\mahemad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\smi\rfc1902.py", line 855, in resolveWithMib
    raise SmiError('MIB object %r is not OBJECT-TYPE (MIB not loaded?)' % (self.__args[0],))
pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: MIB object ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.6.4.1.2.1.2.1.3') is not OBJECT-TYPE (MIB not loaded?)

Comment: Also tried errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(setCmd(SnmpEngine(),CommunityData('write_public'),UdpTransportTarget(('xx.xx.xx.xx', 161)),ContextData(),ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.6.4.1.2.1.2.1.3'),0).addAsn1MibSource('file:///d:/mib/pdu2_mib.txt'))) same error

Comment: tried this too 
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(setCmd(SnmpEngine(),CommunityData('write_public'),UdpTransportTarget(('xx.xxx.xx.xx', 161)),ContextData(),ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.6.4.1.2.1.2.1.3'),0).addAsn1MibSource('file:///d:/mib/'))) same error

Answer (score 0):

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(setCmd(SnmpEngine(),CommunityData('write_public'),UdpTransportTarget(('xx.xx.xx.xx', 161)),ContextData(),)ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.6.4.1.2.1.2.1.3'), Integer(0)))
```

Type of the value your setting must be specified and I'm figuring out how to add mibs ...mibs does not make any major difference if not added, it's just for print statements.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).